# React setState hook from scroll event listener

Tags: javascript, reactjs, addeventlistener, react-hooks

First of all, with a class component, this works fine and does not cause any issues.

However, in functional component with hooks, whenever I try to set state from my scroll event listener's function `handleScroll`, my state fails to get updated or app's performance gets affected drastically even though I am using debounce.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import debounce from "debounce";

let prevScrollY = 0;

const App = () => {
  const [goingUp, setGoingUp] = useState(false);

  const handleScroll = () => {
    const currentScrollY = window.scrollY;
    if (prevScrollY < currentScrollY && goingUp) {
      debounce(() => {
        setGoingUp(false);
      }, 1000);
    }
    if (prevScrollY > currentScrollY && !goingUp) {
      debounce(() => {
        setGoingUp(true);
      }, 1000);
    }

    prevScrollY = currentScrollY;
    console.log(goingUp, currentScrollY);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <div style={{ background: "orange", height: 100, margin: 10 }} />
      <div style={{ background: "orange", height: 100, margin: 10 }} />
      <div style={{ background: "orange", height: 100, margin: 10 }} />
      <div style={{ background: "orange", height: 100, margin: 10 }} />
      <div style={{ background: "orange", height: 100, margin: 10 }} />
      <div style={{ background: "orange", height: 100, margin: 10 }} />
      <div style={{ background: "orange", height: 100, margin: 10 }} />
      <div style={{ background: "orange", height: 100, margin: 10 }} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Tried to use `useCallback` hook in `handleScroll` function but it did not help much.

What am I doing wrong? How can I set state from `handleScroll` without a huge impact on performance?

I've created a sandbox with this issue.

[image: Edit React setState from event listener]

Comment: you're still creating the handlescroll for every tick of your debounce. you should memoize it. your unmount is still calling `addEventListener` rather than `removeEventListener`. Both of those can cause issues :)

Comment: @JohnRuddell hey, thanks for spotting the mistake on `removeEventListener`. However, this causes memory leaks but is not linked to the performance issue I am trying to solve. It was just a typo and on the original project is with remove instead of add, but the issue persists

Comment: no it totally is, because you can setup hundreds of listeners with a simple scroll. which means each callback is trying to fire hundres of times per debounce tick.

Comment: @JohnRuddell ok, but this would happen only if I would unmount and re-mount my component hundreds of times (and that is not the case here) because the current effect runs only on mount/unmount.

Comment: yep, so you should probably memoize handle scroll. or better yet, not drop class syntax since you already have a working solution.

Comment: @JohnRuddell I've tried moving `handleScroll` outside the component with more properties. This way it does not get recreated every time. I believed that this results in the same way, doesn't it?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In your code I see several issues:

1) `[]` in useEffect means it will not see any changes of state, like changes of `goingUp`. It will always see initial value of `goingUp`

2) `debounce` does not work so. It returns a new debounced function.

3) usually global variables is an anti-pattern, thought it works just in your case.

4) your scroll listener is not passive, as mentioned by @skyboyer.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const prevScrollY = useRef(0);

  const [goingUp, setGoingUp] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleScroll = () => {
      const currentScrollY = window.scrollY;
      if (prevScrollY.current < currentScrollY && goingUp) {
        setGoingUp(false);
      }
      if (prevScrollY.current > currentScrollY && !goingUp) {
        setGoingUp(true);
      }

      prevScrollY.current = currentScrollY;
      console.log(goingUp, currentScrollY);
    };

    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll, { passive: true });

    return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
  }, [goingUp]);

  return (
    <div>
      <div style={{ background: "orange", height: 100, margin: 10 }} />
      <div style={{ background: "orange", height: 100, margin: 10 }} />
      <div style={{ background: "orange", height: 100, margin: 10 }} />
      <div style={{ background: "orange", height: 100, margin: 10 }} />
      <div style={{ background: "orange", height: 100, margin: 10 }} />
      <div style={{ background: "orange", height: 100, margin: 10 }} />
      <div style={{ background: "orange", height: 100, margin: 10 }} />
      <div style={{ background: "orange", height: 100, margin: 10 }} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-setstate-from-event-listener-q7to8

Comment: Great advices, this is awesome, thank you! Just one question - now whenever `goingUp` changes, useEffect is called (isn't it?). This means that everytime it is called, event listener is added. Wouldn't this cause memory leaks?

Comment: useEffect will be called whenever `goingUp` is changed, as long as user does not change direction of scrolling hundreds of times per second performance will be fine.

Comment: And there is no memory leak: every time `goingUp` is changed it will call `removeEventListener`

Comment: I don't think you should worry about `useEffect` performance yet. Code on codesandbox shows it is fast enough. 
If you still would like improve performance even more you could memoise listener by using `useDispatch`. https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/ . But I think it is a bad trade between the simplicity of the code and its performance

Answer (score 9):

> In short, you need to add `goingUp` as the dependency of useEffect.

If you use `[]`, you will only create/remove a listener with a function(`handleScroll`, which is created in the initial render). In other words, when re-render, the scroll event listener is still using the old `handleScroll` from the initial render.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
  }, [goingUp]);
```

> Using custom hooks

I recommend move the whole logic into a custom hooks, which can make your code more clear and easy to reuse. I use `useRef` to store the previous value.

```
export function useScrollDirection() {
  const prevScrollY = useRef(0)
  const [goingUp, setGoingUp] = useState(false);

  const handleScroll = () => {
    const currentScrollY = window.scrollY;
    if (prevScrollY.current < currentScrollY && goingUp) {
      setGoingUp(false);
    }
    if (prevScrollY.current > currentScrollY && !goingUp) {
      setGoingUp(true);
    }
    prevScrollY.current = currentScrollY;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
  }, [goingUp]); 
  return goingUp ? 'up' : 'down';
}
```

Comment: I agree, this approach looks very clean and readable. Thank you, great insight.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand hooks but what if I want to add another custom hook that also listens to the scroll event but returns different data such as 'top' or 'bottom' when the scroll reaches the top of bottom of the window. Would these two hooks interfere with each other?

Answer (score 3):

Your are re-creating `handleScroll` function on each render so it's refers to actual data(`goingup`) so you don't need `useCallback` here.

But besides you recreate `handleScroll` you are set as event listener only first instance of it - since you give `useEffect(..., [])` it runs only once on mount.

The one solution is to re-subscribe to `scroll` with up-to-date `handleScroll`. To do that you have to return cleanup function within `useEffect`(by now it returns one more subscribing) and remove `[]` to run it on each render:

```
useEffect(() => {
  window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
  return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
});
```

PS and you better use [passive event listener](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/audits/passive-event-listeners) for scroll.

Comment: Removing dependencies array from this effect does not help and instead calls add listener on every render. And even when I move `handleScroll` outside the function to prevent the recreation of it the issue still persists. All I need to do is to somehow determine when a user is scrolling up or down.

Comment: and it should call `addEventListener` on each render. otherwise you need much more complex way to both make handler using actual data(not stale one) and making it debounced.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution for this case

```js
const [pageUp, setPageUp] = useState(false)
const lastScroll = useRef(0)

const checkScrollTop = () => {
  const currentScroll = window.pageYOffset
  setPageUp(lastScroll.current > currentScroll)
  lastScroll.current = currentScroll
}

// lodash throttle function
const throttledFunc = throttle(checkScrollTop, 400, { leading: true })

useEffect(() => {
  window.addEventListener("scroll", throttledFunc, false)
  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener("scroll", throttledFunc)
  }
}, [])
```

Adding event listeners should be once when `componentDidMount` only. not in every changes causes by `pageUp`. So, we don't need to add `pageUp` to `useEffect` dependencies.

[image: Edit toggle on scroll]

`Hint:` you can add `throttledFunc` to `useEffect` if it changes and you need to re-render the component

Answer (score -1):

```
const objDiv = document.getElementById('chat_body');
objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
```

Comment: Could you please annotate your code or add an explanation above the code sample to explain how it works, so that this answer is applicable generally and not just in OP's specific use-case?